# ip forwarding using iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding

I have two interface in my linux machine , one is configured for public ip `110.111.250.241 - eth0`, another is for LAN `10.42.43.1`. I have a client machine `10.42.43.174` with apache web server.

I want to access port 80 of `10.42.43.174` from internet (home or somewhere else). So I need port forwarding by `iptables`. In `sysctl` `ip_forward` is 1, I tried to set some prerouting iptable rule but I am still unable to access port 80 of 10.42.43.174 for my public ip.

Comment: Show us what rules you've got set; pasting the outputs of `iptables -L -n -v` and `iptables -t nat -L -n -v` into your question would be a good way to do that.

Comment: i tried iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d 110.111.250.241 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.42.43.174:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -d 10.42.43.174 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Comment: That is worse than useless, because `iptables` rules are position-dependent; you may have put earlier ones that contradict, forbid, or render irrelevant what you've posted above.  In fact, given that what you've posted above looks good on its own, this is almost certainly the case.  **We need to see your whole ruleset** before we can suggest what changes need to be made.

Comment: i have many rules in iptables and i can not flush it . my whole internet in running on iptables rules.

Comment: Who's asking you to **flush** the rules?  We want you to **list** them.  If there are that many, you might want to add `--line-numbers` to the commands above.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this rule, which should do the job? If not, as mentioned by MadHatter, you should provide `iptables -L -n -v` and `iptables -t nat -L -n -v` output

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 --to-destination 10.42.43.1:80
```

Comment: 10.42.43.1 is the IP of my another interface of my linux router, then how it will redirect to 10.42.43.174

Comment: When prerouting, you need to specify the input interface. How will the kernel redirect to 10.42.43.174? Just by looking up in the routing table which should contain an entry like `10.42.43.0 255.255.255.0 eth1` if your network is a /24 (which is not important here, just to illustrate the routing table)

Comment: `--to-destination 10.42.43.1:80` is wrong. It should be DNATed to 10.42.43.174, not 10.42.43.1.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are correct, but there's an SNAT or MASQUERADE rule missing for rewriting the source IP to the routing machines IP. The complete set would be:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d 110.111.250.241 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.42.43.174
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -d 10.42.43.174 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: @etagneklo, would want to add -s 10.14.43.0/24, to that -t NAT -A POSTROUTING -o eht1, otherwise, people *could* route masq inside?

Comment: The MASQERADE rule will rewrite the source address to 10.42.43.1. `-s 10.14.43.0/24` will not work as the rule will not match then for packets that come from outside of your LAN. I also don't get why this should be a problem, as you WANT packets to get routed inside.

Comment: i have tried all above rules but i didn't get anything. currently i am working with ssh tunnel but it is not my permanent solution.

Comment: -s does nothing on -j MASQ, i meant exec -j DROP, so people coulndt relay thru and take on router ip